# training parametric circuits in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

The following is an official example of qiskit training simple parameter circuits (https://learn.qiskit.org/summer-school/2021/lab4-introduction-training-quantum-circuits). But they mainly focus on how to choose the gradient, and how to visualize the gradient. I have a question, do all parameters need to go through gradient descent? Or gradient descent for only some of the parameters as in the case? In addition, is there a use case for batched parameter gradient descent? Why does this case only describe the curve of the gradient, but not the curve of the loss function, is it because the gradient contains the loss function?

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes
from qiskit.opflow import Z, I
from qiskit.opflow import StateFn
import numpy as np
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.opflow import PauliExpectation, CircuitSampler
from qiskit.opflow import Gradient
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import GradientDescent
from qiskit.opflow import NaturalGradient

ansatz = RealAmplitudes(num_qubits=2, reps=1, entanglement='linear').decompose()
ansatz.draw('mpl', style='iqx')

hamiltonian = Z ^ Z

expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True) @ StateFn(ansatz)

point = np.random.random(ansatz.num_parameters)
index = 2

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
q_instance = QuantumInstance(backend, shots = 8192, seed_simulator = 2718, seed_transpiler = 2718)


expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True) @ StateFn(ansatz)
in_pauli_basis = PauliExpectation().convert(expectation)
sampler = CircuitSampler(q_instance)

def evaluate_expectation(x):
    value_dict = dict(zip(ansatz.parameters, x))
    result = sampler.convert(in_pauli_basis, params=value_dict).eval()  
    return np.real(result)

eps = 0.2
e_i = np.identity(point.size)[:, index]  # identity vector with a 1 at index ``index``, otherwise 0

plus = point + eps * e_i
minus = point - eps * e_i


finite_difference = (evaluate_expectation(plus) - evaluate_expectation(minus)) / (2 * eps)

print(finite_difference)

expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True) @ StateFn(ansatz)
shifter = Gradient('fin_diff', analytic=False, epsilon=eps)
grad = shifter.convert(expectation, params=ansatz.parameters[index])
print(grad)

value_dict = dict(zip(ansatz.parameters, point))
sampler.convert(grad, value_dict).eval().real

eps = np.pi / 2
e_i = np.identity(point.size)[:, index]  # identity vector with a 1 at index ``index``, otherwise 0

plus = point + eps * e_i
minus = point - eps * e_i

finite_difference = (evaluate_expectation(plus) - evaluate_expectation(minus)) / 2

print(finite_difference)

expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True) @ StateFn(ansatz)
shifter = Gradient()  # parameter-shift rule is the default
grad = shifter.convert(expectation, params=ansatz.parameters[index])
sampler.convert(grad, value_dict).eval().real

expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True) @ StateFn(ansatz)
shifter = Gradient('lin_comb')  # parameter-shift rule is the default
grad = shifter.convert(expectation, params=ansatz.parameters[index])
sampler.convert(grad, value_dict).eval().real

# initial_point = np.random.random(ansatz.num_parameters)
initial_point = np.array([0.43253681, 0.09507794, 0.42805949, 0.34210341])

expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True).compose(StateFn(ansatz))  
gradient = Gradient().convert(expectation)
gradient_in_pauli_basis = PauliExpectation().convert(gradient)
sampler = CircuitSampler(q_instance)

def evaluate_gradient(x):
    value_dict = dict(zip(ansatz.parameters, x))
    result = sampler.convert(gradient_in_pauli_basis, params=value_dict).eval()  # add parameters in here!
    return np.real(result)    

gd_loss = []
def gd_callback(nfevs, x, fx, stepsize):
    gd_loss.append(fx)
    
gd = GradientDescent(maxiter=300, learning_rate=0.01, callback=gd_callback)

x_opt, fx_opt, nfevs = gd.optimize(initial_point.size,    # number of parameters
                                   evaluate_expectation,  # function to minimize
                                   gradient_function=evaluate_gradient,  # function to evaluate the gradient
                                   initial_point=initial_point)  # initial point

import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 14

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(gd_loss, label='vanilla gradient descent')
plt.axhline(-1, ls='--', c='tab:red', label='target')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('iterations')
plt.legend()

expectation = StateFn(hamiltonian, is_measurement=True).compose(StateFn(ansatz))  
natural_gradient = NaturalGradient(regularization='ridge').convert(expectation)
natural_gradient_in_pauli_basis = PauliExpectation().convert(natural_gradient)
sampler = CircuitSampler(q_instance, caching="all")

def evaluate_natural_gradient(x):
    value_dict = dict(zip(ansatz.parameters, x))
    result = sampler.convert(natural_gradient, params=value_dict).eval()  
    return np.real(result)    

print('Vanilla gradient:', evaluate_gradient(initial_point))
print('Natural gradient:', evaluate_natural_gradient(initial_point))

qng_loss = []
def qng_callback(nfevs, x, fx, stepsize):
    qng_loss.append(fx)
    
qng = GradientDescent(maxiter=300, learning_rate=0.01, callback=qng_callback)

x_opt, fx_opt, nfevs = qng.optimize(initial_point.size, 
                                    evaluate_expectation, 
                                    gradient_function=evaluate_natural_gradient,
                                    initial_point=initial_point)

def plot_loss():
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(gd_loss, 'tab:blue', label='vanilla gradient descent')
    plt.plot(qng_loss, 'tab:green', label='quantum natural gradient')
    plt.axhline(-1, c='tab:red', ls='--', label='target')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('iterations')
    plt.legend()
    
plot_loss()


from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA

spsa_loss = []
def spsa_callback(nfev, x, fx, stepsize, accepted):
    spsa_loss.append(fx)

spsa = SPSA(maxiter=300, learning_rate=0.01, perturbation=0.01, callback=spsa_callback)

x_opt, fx_opt, nfevs = spsa.optimize(initial_point.size, 
                                     evaluate_expectation, 
                                     initial_point=initial_point)

def plot_loss():
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(gd_loss, 'tab:blue', label='vanilla gradient descent')
    plt.plot(qng_loss, 'tab:green', label='quantum natural gradient')
    plt.plot(spsa_loss, 'tab:blue', ls='--', label='SPSA')
    plt.axhline(-1, c='tab:red', ls='--', label='target')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('iterations')
    plt.legend()
    
plot_loss()

from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import QNSPSA

qnspsa_loss = []
def qnspsa_callback(nfev, x, fx, stepsize, accepted):
    qnspsa_loss.append(fx)

fidelity = QNSPSA.get_fidelity(ansatz, q_instance, expectation=PauliExpectation())
qnspsa = QNSPSA(fidelity, maxiter=300, learning_rate=0.01, perturbation=0.01, callback=qnspsa_callback)

x_opt, fx_opt, nfevs = qnspsa.optimize(initial_point.size, 
                                       evaluate_expectation, 
                                       initial_point=initial_point)

def plot_loss():
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(gd_loss, 'tab:blue', label='vanilla gradient descent')
    plt.plot(qng_loss, 'tab:green', label='quantum natural gradient')
    plt.plot(spsa_loss, 'tab:blue', ls='--', label='SPSA')
    plt.plot(qnspsa_loss, 'tab:green', ls='--', label='QN-SPSA')
    plt.axhline(-1, c='tab:red', ls='--', label='target')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('iterations')
    plt.legend()
    
plot_loss()

autospsa_loss = []
def autospsa_callback(nfev, x, fx, stepsize, accepted):
    autospsa_loss.append(fx)

autospsa = SPSA(maxiter=300, learning_rate=None, perturbation=None, callback=autospsa_callback)

x_opt, fx_opt, nfevs = autospsa.optimize(initial_point.size, 
                                         evaluate_expectation, 
                                         initial_point=initial_point)

def plot_loss():
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(gd_loss, 'tab:blue', label='vanilla gradient descent')
    plt.plot(qng_loss, 'tab:green', label='quantum natural gradient')
    plt.plot(spsa_loss, 'tab:blue', ls='--', label='SPSA')
    plt.plot(qnspsa_loss, 'tab:green', ls='--', label='QN-SPSA')
    plt.plot(autospsa_loss, 'tab:red', label='Powerlaw SPSA')
    plt.axhline(-1, c='tab:red', ls='--', label='target')
    plt.ylabel('loss')
    plt.xlabel('iterations')
    plt.legend()
    
plot_loss()
```

Comment: side comment. What do you mean by "official example"? I failed to find in the documentation. Maybe you can add the link?

Comment: https://learn.qiskit.org/summer-school/2021/lab4-introduction-training-quantum-circuits

Answer (score 4):

It focuses on selecting the gradients because this code is from the Qiskit Global Summer School on Machine Learning from 2021, from a lecture on how to train quantum circuits! If you follow the full lecture you can see that each type of optimization is explained and finally all are compared. So this is not really an "official" Qiskit tutorial ;)

The plots do show the loss, since the loss is just the function value we optimize. So a snippet like

```
gd_loss = []
def gd_callback(nfevs, x, fx, stepsize):
    gd_loss.append(fx)
```

does store the loss, which is the function value `fx`.

In variational quantum algorithms, the "batch size" is sometimes associated with the number of measurements per expectation value. In the snippet above the number of shots is set to 8192, so that could be associated with the batch size. But since there are no epochs and no data to optimize over, I'm not sure if that's a very useful analogy :)